# HP L2105tm Touch Screen WORKS

Tags: touchscreen

What is the best way to get the word out that HP's $300 USD 21.5" touch screen monitor "just works" on a Raspberry Pi?

I searched forever before finding one tiny reference on the fifth page of search results where one person said it worked, so I took a chance and got a few.

If you want a nice big bright 1080 touch screen on a Pi for cheap, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be best posting such things on either the raspberry pi official forum, the recommended peripherals subforum here : http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=46&sid=d09441d53bf8c19f9fe679e5995cef8a, **or** making an entry in the raspberry pi hardware wiki for touchscreens here : http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Touch_Screen